# How to create playFramework application's WAR file and deploy it in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6, playframework

May I know the way to create a `war` file which work same as the application while running in `playFramework`? As I tried on Windows XP, running `play war mayapp  -o myapp.war` resulted in a `myapp.war` folder. I then placed the folder into Tomcat 6 in the webapps directory.

Then, I started `myapp.war` in Tomcat by going to `https:localhost:8080/myapp.war`.

Problem is: my application at above URL behaves wrongly. There is no CSS nor Javascript. The webpage URLs are not in the expected form.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is due to the concept of a WAR context. Take a look at the following related question, which should solve your problem.

[how to use "war.context" in Configuration file of Play Framework ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358286/how-to-use-war-context-in-configuration-file-of-play-framework)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this url:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Can you see the CSS this way?