# Play Framework, WARs and Tomcat 6 deployment exception

Tags: exception, tomcat, deployment, playframework, war

I've created a `Play 1.2.3` app and I'm trying to deploy its `war` file to Tomcat 6, but I keep getting this exception.

I generate the `war` file, enabling the "production" profile, with:

```
play war webapp -o webapp.war --%production --zip
```

I get two files:

1. A `webapp.war` folder
2. A `webapp.war.war` file

I move the `webapp.war.war` file into the webapps folder of Tomcat, renaming the file to `webapp.war`. When I start Tomcat and try to execute the app, the following exception appears:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class play.server.ServletWrapper
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.scanPrecompiled(ApplicationClassloader.java:527)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:385)
    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:550)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:291)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper.contextInitialized(ServletWrapper.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried the following ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358286/how-to-use-war-context-in-configuration-file-of-play-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this

```
play war webapp -o temp --%production --zip
```

after you get the temp.war, rename it into webapp.war, then deploy
HTH