# Play 1.2.x on WebSphere 8

Tags: playframework, websphere, javassist

I want to deploy a simple Play (1.2.4) application to WebSphere 8.  I have the application working locally on Windows. Both are Java 1.6. I created a WAR file using:

```
play clean
play war --zip -o c:\sampleapp
```

then modified the generated web.xml to define my server Datasource, build the war file again and deployed. During the deployment it found my resource-ref from the web.xml and I bound it to the WAS defined datasource. Then I changed classloader order to "parent last" (based on the Play deployment options pages and other threads). Then I started the application with no errors.

I have a class which extends play.jobs.Job with a method marked @OnApplicationStart. When I start the newly installed application through the WAS console, it starts up and executes this method which connects to the datasource and loads up some data and puts it into cache.

The problem comes as soon as I try to access my first Controller, where I get this error:

```
[9/17/12 16:19:48:132 CDT] 00000022 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [sampleapp] [/sampleapp] [play]: Initialization successful.
[9/17/12 16:19:48:773 CDT] 00000022 SystemOut     O 16:19:48,772 ERROR ~

@6bl9mfbm1
Internal Server Error (500)

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 41)
RuntimeException occured : play.mvc.Scope$Session

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: play.mvc.Scope$Session
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.execute(ServletWrapper.java:557)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.run(ServletWrapper.java:548)
        at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:68)
        at play.server.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:142)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: play.mvc.Scope$Session
        at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:156)
        at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)
        at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)
        at controllers.Application.connected(Application.java:41)
        at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:49)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
        ... 28 more
```

Here is my relevant Controller code:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    @Before(unless={"login","index"})
    static void addUser() {
        User user = connected();
        if(user != null) {
            flash.put("user", user);
//          renderArgs.put("user", user);
        } else {
            flash.error("Please log in.");
            index();
        }

    }

    static User connected() {
//        if(renderArgs.get("user") != null) {
//            return renderArgs.get("user", User.class);
//        }
        String username = session.get("user");   // Line 41 - Error!
        if(username != null) {
            return User.find("byUsername", username).first();
        } 
        return null;
    }

    public static void index() {
        if(connected() != null) {
            Download.index(1);
        }
        render();
    }  
    ..
    ..
}
```

The error appears to come from the session reference. Note that the commented lines referencing renderArgs also caused a similar error when active.

Is javassist not "enhancing" properly somewhere? I tried replacing the javassist jar with the latest version, with the same result.

I'm trying really hard to get Play in the "enterprise" here, so I'd really like this to work. As of September 2012 I can't tell if Play has run on WAS8 successfully or not. I would consider Play 2 (java) but it seems to be **definitely** not WAS supported, and the plugin play2war looks to not have WAS support yet either. Silly that we can't run without WAS, but this is the reality of our enterprise.

**Update**:
I've also tried Play 1.2.5 now and created a new app and added a single line, session.get("x") to the Application.index method. Deployed the war file and got the same error at first access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a specific solution to your problem.

However, consider the following threads for leads.

- [WebSphere Application Server and Play!Framework](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/websphere$20Yan/play-framework/dB9DGM7wLrI/JHhOT_0uyPAJ)
- [How to deploy Play app to Websphere 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388217/how-to-deploy-play-app-to-websphere-7)

However, try the mailing list as well (play-framework@googlegroups.com) to see if someone has a solution or come across the same problem. You can also google through the mailing list.

Generally though, it is recommended to use the play server in production as well, as it is good enough. If you want you can put apache/nginx infront as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue could be solved by tweaking the classloader settings in WebSphere. If the thought of this makes you shudder and you wish WAS would just get out of the way, you could do  try this workaround.

Create a startup job similar to this:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Startup extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        javassist.runtime.Desc.useContextClassLoader = true;
    }
}
```